# Python - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append' - maths game

Tags: python, math, attributes, scoring

Trying to make it so a user can add a name, score and what difficulty the user completed the game on to high scores list.

```
def teacher_page():
    global scores, name, difficulties
    t_choice = None
    while t_choice !="0":
        print("\nWhat would you like to do?")
        print(
        """
        0 - Main Menu
        1 - Add a score
        2 - Remove a score
        3 - View highscores
        """
        )

        t_choice = input("Choice: ")
        print()

    #exit
        if t_choice == "0":
            main_menu()
    #add a score
        elif t_choice == "1":
            names = input("Name of the new user to add?\n")
            name.append(names)
            score = input("What did the user score?\n")
            scores.append(score)
            difficulty = input("And which difficulty did they complete it on?\n")
            difficulties.append(difficulty)
    #remove a score
        elif t_choice == "2":      
            names = input("Name of the user you want to remove?\n")
            if names in name:
                name.remove(names)          
            score = int(input("What did they score?\n"))
            if score in scores:
                scores.remove(score)
    #view highscores
        elif t_choice == "3":
            print("High Scores:")
            for score in scores:
                print(name, score, "on the difficulty ", difficulties)
    #if the t_choice does not = to 0,1,2,3
        else:
            print("Sorry but", t_choice, "isn't a vaild choice.")
```

But every-time I want to add a user to the list I get the error message

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I've had a look at a few examples but not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Strings don't have an `append` method, as the error says. Are you expecting scores to be a string, or a list? Could be `name` too. Show the exact error with trace.

Comment: Well the problem is that what you think is a list is actually a string.

Comment: Programming/Project/testing2.py", line 121, in teacher_page
    name.append(names)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Are these global variables `scores, name` a list type?

Comment: So what is the type of your `name` object? It isn't defined in your example, but clearly it is not a list

Comment: These are my global variables 
scores = []
choice = None
name = []
difficulties = []

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize your variables as **lists** right below their declaration.

By default, when you assign raw input to them for the first time, they become strings.

Do something like:

```
global scores, name, difficulties
scores=[]
name=[]
difficulties=[]
```

During global declaration. Need not initialize again within the function.